# Espresso matcher for a RecyclerView item with ID and visibility

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

I found some code in another thread that allows me to match against items in a `RecyclerView`;

```
fun atPosition(position: Int, itemMatcher: Matcher<View?>): Matcher<View?>? {
            return object : BoundedMatcher<View?, RecyclerView>(RecyclerView::class.java) {
                override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
                    description.appendText("has item at position $position: ")
                    itemMatcher.describeTo(description)
                }

                override fun matchesSafely(view: RecyclerView): Boolean {
                    val viewHolder = view.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position)
                        ?: // has no item on such position
                        return false
                    return itemMatcher.matches(viewHolder.itemView)
                }
            }
        }
```

I can then use it like this;

```
onView(withId(R.id.rv)).check(matches(Utils.atPosition(0, hasDescendant(withText("test")))))
```

However, if the thing I want to check against requires an id and that its visible then it doesn't work.

This doesn't work because (I believe) that `isDisplayed()` is checked against the position `View` in the `RecyclerView`, rather than the textview component;

```
onView(withId(R.id.rv)).check(matches(Utils.atPosition(0, hasDescendant(allOf(withId(R.id.textview), isDisplayed())))))
```

In order to hack the code to get it working I replaced a method with the following code;

```
override fun matchesSafely(view: RecyclerView): Boolean {
                val viewHolder = view.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position)
                    ?: // has no item on such position
                    return false
                return viewHolder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview).isVisible
            }
```

This is clearly a horrible solution and I would like one that is less terrible.